# Interstitial Ad not show in splash screen activity

Tags: java, admob, interstitial

I'm trying to integrate Interstitial Ad in splash screen activity
by using this [tutorial](https://ads-developers.googleblog.com/2014/04/how-to-create-google-mobile-ads-splash.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20GoogleAdsDeveloperBlog%20(Google%20Ads%20Developer%20Blog)) 
.. but the ad not loading.

can anyone tell me where is the problem please?

thanks in advance

here is my code :

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity {
private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
        private Timer waitTimer;
    private boolean interstitialCanceled;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);




 mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_full_screen));
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener()


{
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        if (!interstitialCanceled) {
            waitTimer.cancel();
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
        startHomeMain();
    }
});

waitTimer = new Timer();
waitTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        interstitialCanceled = true;
        SplashScreenActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startHomeMain();
            }
        });
    }
}, 5000);
} // end of onCreate implementation.

private void startHomeMain() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeMain.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    waitTimer.cancel();
    interstitialCanceled = true;
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
    } else if (interstitialCanceled) {
        startHomeMain();
    }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to integrate Interstitial Ad in splash screen activity
by using this [tutorial](https://ads-developers.googleblog.com/2014/04/how-to-create-google-mobile-ads-splash.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20GoogleAdsDeveloperBlog%20(Google%20Ads%20Developer%20Blog)) 
.. but the ad not loading.

can anyone tell me where is the problem please?

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share your logcat about loading ads? There should be an error code of ads

Comment: Tested it on a real device already? Loading issues are normal on emulators?

Comment: yes but not showing ads. i have interstitial ad in other activities it working good.. but in this place not

Answer (score 0):

Google ads takes minimum 6 seconds to Load , and in your code you have set timer of 5 seconds , so thats why your Splash screen activity finished but ad not shown

try to set timer of greater than 6 seconds , and display add on destroy method of activity.

Comment: thanks for you reply
i've tried 10 seconds but not working

Answer (score 0):

Remove timer and add progress dialogue and in onAdLoaded Dismiss dialogue and show ad as well as Dismiss dialogue in onFailedtoLoad